# Mesh is not showing in physics even after baking

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh

I am a beginner and tried liquid simulation but I am not able to use mesh in physics because it's not showing.

[image: in the picture added you can see there is no mesh option]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead. See [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org), so we don't have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges, a hardware issue such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Answer (score 1):

Tap on the little arrow left of "Liquid" to open the panel -> then you will see "Mesh".

If the arrow points to the right, this means, the panel is collapsed.
If the arrow points down it means: panel is "open" and shows its content.

[image]